# How do I prove 2 indifference curves have the same properties?

Tags: utility, preferences

[image]

I understand questions a) but I'm completely stumped at c).

What do they mean by U'=1 having same properties as U=10??

And w,for questions b and c, what are they asking by "general expression for MRS"?

Comment: You should try to typeset your question rather than post a picture. The answers are not usable by others anymore if the picture link is lost.